# Using sp_helptext on a encrypted store procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, encryption

Yesterday I created a store procedure with encryption for an exercise purposes but I forgot to save the query.

Today I was planning to view the tsql code by using

```
exec sp_helptext 'procedure_name'
```

But since it is encrypted I can't see the code. I was wondering if there is a way to solve this?

Comment: This [article](http://sqljunkieshare.com/2012/03/07/decrypting-encrypted-stored-procedures-views-functions-in-sql-server-20052008-r2/) goes into a lot of details on how to decrypt such objects.. also I am assuming you are using `sql-server` since you have tagged as `tsql`

Comment: Thank you @vmachan  great article. I will try to understand the decryption code. Is there anyway to select your comment as an answer?

Comment: Thanks! I added the an answer with some more description so that hopefully more folks can maybe benefit from the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the article in the comment as an answer so that more folks may benefit

This [article](http://sqljunkieshare.com/2012/03/07/decrypting-encrypted-stored-procedures-views-functions-in-sql-server-20052008-r2/) goes into a lot of details on how to decrypt such objects..

It talks about a basic approach using code to decrypt the code from the system tables as well as using 3rd party tools such as DAC and Optillect (which it seems does not need admin privileges)

NOTE: I am assuming you are using sql-server since you have tagged as tsql